# Warning: Received `false` for a non-boolean attribute. How do I pass a boolean for a custom boolean attribute?

Tags: reactjs, styled-components, react-16

```
Warning: Received `false` for a non-boolean attribute `comingsoon`.

If you want to write it to the DOM, pass a string instead: 
comingsoon="false" or comingsoon={value.toString()}.
```

How do I pass a boolean in a custom attribute for React?

I'm using styled-components and passing the attribute through the component. Here is a picture of how I'm passing the attr.

[image]
[passing boolean custom attr as "comingsoon"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/490By.png)

[image]
[styled-components css props](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cbhsK.png)

Comment: Unrelated, but which vs code theme are you using ?

Answer (score 109, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
comingsoon={value ? 1 : 0}
```

Comment: This worked for me. Why does this work and not boolean?

Comment: This accepted answer is not correct, please scroll down to **transient-props**. Reference: https://styled-components.com/docs/api#transient-props.

Comment: this is what works in my case: `resettable={condition ? true : undefined}`

Comment: @EvgenyBobkin is correct, the right one is using transient-props. Please see the other answer

Comment: typscript won't accept this :(((((((((((((((

Answer (score 128):

As of `5.1` you can now use [transient props](https://styled-components.com/docs/api#transient-props) (`$`) which prevents the props being passed to the DOM element.

```
const Comp = styled.div`
  color: ${props =>
    props.$draggable || 'black'};
`;

render(
  <Comp $draggable="red" draggable="true">
    Drag me!
  </Comp>
);
```

Comment: I got the following error on the console.
```
Warning: Invalid attribute name: `$datasuccess`
```

Answer (score 43):

You have to add `$` prefix to attribute:

```
$comingsoon={value}
```

Styled Components had added transient props in 5.1 version:
https://styled-components.com/docs/api#transient-props

Answer (score 15):

In my case, it was because I was accidentally passing `{...@props}` down into a div.

Usually passing `attribute={false}` is fine, but not to native elements.

Answer (score 8):

Just make it a number instead, this is the workaround from https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components/issues/1198:

Comment: This passes the value to the DOM and with styled-components it's not really what you want though. Even though this is an easy way to remove the warning.

Comment: Using the same link, I found this solution (https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components/issues/1198#issuecomment-425650423) even though some say it's not the best.

Answer (score 8):

Similar to Frank Lins answer above but I had to use undefined instead of 0 to get rid of the warning:

```
comingsoon={value ? 1 : undefined}
```

Answer (score 8):

This error with `styled-components` appears to be due to `styled()` attempting to apply a boolean to an element in the DOM, but DOM elements only accept strings as attributes.

This is well documented in the `styled-components` repository here: https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components/issues/1198

There are two solutions:

1. Lift the styled component w/ the passed attribute up, so that the attribute is not applied to the element directly. Or,
2. Filter the passed attribute out of the props when calling styled components.

Both of these options are demonstrated in the code below.

CodeSandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-thunder-9w132?file=/src/App.tsx

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import styled from 'styled-components';

// demonstration of two different solutions for solving the styled-components error:
// `Warning: Received `false` for a non-boolean attribute`
// Solution 1: Lift the attribute up into a wrapper.
// Solution 2: Filter-out the `toggle` attribute passed to styled-component.

interface BtnProps {
  toggle: boolean;
}

const Container = styled.div`
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
`;

const StyledBtnOne = styled.div<BtnProps>`
  & button {
    background-color: ${({toggle}) => toggle ? ' #2ecc71' : '' };
  };
`;

const StyledBtnTwo = styled(({primary, ...props}) =>
  <button {...(({toggle, ...propz}) => propz)(props)} />)<BtnProps>`
  background-color: ${({toggle}) => toggle ? ' #3498db' : '' };
`;

const App = () => {

  const [ btnOne, setBtnOne ] = useState(false);

  const [ btnTwo, setBtnTwo ] = useState(false);

  const triggerOne = () => setBtnOne(!btnOne);

  const triggerTwo = () => setBtnTwo(!btnTwo);

  return (
    <Container>
      <StyledBtnOne toggle={btnOne}>
        <button 
          onClick={triggerOne}>
            Solution 1
        </button>
      </StyledBtnOne>

      <StyledBtnTwo 
        toggle={btnTwo}
        onClick={triggerTwo}>
        Solution 2
      </StyledBtnTwo>
    </Container>
  );

}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 5):

Add "+" before your booleans values.

```
comingsoon = {+creator.comingSoon}
```

example below from the [Link to answer](https://maximeblanc.fr/blog/how-to-fix-the-received-true-for-a-non-boolean-attribute-error/)

```
import styled from "styled-components";
import { Link } from "react-router";

const StyledLink = styled(Link)`
  color: ${({ inverted }) => (inverted ? "white" : "chartreuse")};
`;

function Navbar() {
  return (
    <nav>
      {# Bad #}
      <StyledLink inverted={true}>Home</StyledLink>

      {# Good #}
      <StyledLink inverted={+true}>About</StyledLink>
    </nav>
  );
}
```

Comment: I can't edit this answer, but the link to the answer is broken. Here's the link it's supposed to be: https://maximeblanc.fr/blog/how-to-fix-the-received-true-for-a-non-boolean-attribute-error

Answer (score 3):

This warning can be caused also if the property of styled component has the name existing in HTML. For example I had such issue when named property `wrap`. After renaming warning disappeared.

Answer (score 2):

Solved this by enclosing with brackets `{}` the `boolean` variable I was passing through `props`.

```js
const childrenWithProps = React.Children.map(props.children, child => {
  return React.cloneElement(child, { showcard: { showCard } }
)});
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I had a class name outside of the `className` attribute like this:

```
<Col className='text-center' py-3>
    <p>Techshop &copy; {currentYear}</p>
</Col>
```

And then I got the error like this:
[image: received true for a non-boolean attribute]

If fixed the error by moving the `py-3` class into the className quotes.

```
<Col className='text-center py-3'>
      <p>Techshop &copy; {currentYear}</p>
</Col>
```

Comment: I've just had something similar.  I accidentally wrote "import" in my tag. It looked like this  <nav import className={....}>

Answer (score 0):

I got this issue and also shows `React Hydration Error` in my Next.js application. In my case it seems Styled component got a custom component and it can't process 'boolean'.

Here is my workaround:

before:

```
styled(Text)<{ center?: boolean}>
// Text is my custom component
```

after:

```
styled.div<{ center?: boolean}>
```

Answer (score 0):

use `...rest` operator instead of passing `props` to the HTML.

```
 const Home = ({comingSoon, ...rest}) => <div {...rest}> content </div>
```