# Warning: Received "true" for non-boolean attribute active

Tags: reactjs, react-router

How can I resolve this warning?

```
Warning: Received `true` for a non-boolean attribute `active`.
```

From this error, I understood not to pass anything other than the standard attributes.
However, I was able to solve the error by changing the argument type from boolean to number.
Why does it work with the number type?

```
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

...
<NavigationArea active={true} to="/nikkei">
...

const NavigationArea = styled(Link)<{ active: boolean }>`
  width: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 8px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: ${(props) => (props.active ? "#22AFFF" : "#808080")};
`;
```

Comment: similar Q asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49784294/warning-received-false-for-a-non-boolean-attribute-how-do-i-pass-a-boolean-f)

Answer (score 1):

You can use string type in props value below is the code

active="true"